# Tell Adium not to send that i'm typing

Tags: privacy, adium

I don't want my chat partner to get notified whenever i start or stop typing. Is it possible to tell Adium not to send the notifications to my chat partner?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is done per account and not in general for all accounts. Go to Preferences, Accounts, then click on a particular account, and Edit. In the next window, click on Privacy and uncheck the box after Typing.